# Files and directories remain unwritable after permissions change

Tags: linux, apache, joomla, file-permissions

I am having this issue that I just don't seem to wrap my head around. 
I uploaded a joomla site throught FTP, But all files and directories are unwritable. I have changed the owner and group to apache/apache ... tried every possible combination there is. But I seriously just don't understand the logic. Guys any help would be appreciated ... I have been trying for the last week to figure it out without success.

The apache server is running under user apache and group apache.
File permissions don't seem to change. Althought I ran:

```
sudo find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

I still get the following permission for directories

```
drwxr-xr-x.
```

Comment: Am I right in assuming all directories are set to chmod 755 and file to 644?

Comment: @Lodder Yes, all directories are set to 755 and files to 644

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it. If you run into the same problem, you may want to check this document out
https://superuser.com/questions/298373/file-still-unwriteable-in-var-www-html-after-the-chmod-command